# How to secure NetNamed Pipe binding?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, netnamedpipebinding

How can I able to control the Named Pipe end point security, the end points should only be accessible to the login under which the IIS app pool is running and the administrators group on the local machine?

I have followed this and created necessary Custom binding:
http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2008/06/23/exploring-the-wcf-named-pipe-binding-part-3.aspx

I am wondering how to achieve the IIS app pool part.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) .

You can specify the identity under which the application pool runs, this being a unique account. You can specify a built-in account or a custom account to run the application pool. I think you need to use a custom account.